# Сменить логин входа Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

В Yii2 есть переменная $username через которую осуществляется вход на сайт
Я изменил ей на $email , так как у меня вход через email и password должен быть

Я написал регистрацию через Mysql = данные заносятся БД, но когда собираюсь войти через login.php , данные приходят , но в сессию не заводится и ошибки нет
Меняю переменную $email в на $username = всё работает, пользователь авторизуется

Тыкните где почитать об это и напишите, что я пропустил

LoginForm

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property-read User|null $user
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['email', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    // переводы
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'E-mail',
            'password' => 'Пароль',
            'rememberMe' => 'Запомнить',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect email or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided email and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[email]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->email);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

SiteController

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use app\models\SignupForm;
use app\models\User;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    // Регистрация
    public function actionSignup()
    {
        // проверка доступа к странице
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        //$this->setMeta('Регистрация');
        $model = new SignupForm();

        // проверка поступления данных
        if($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
        {
            $user = new User();
            $user->email = $model->email;
            $user->password = $model->password;
            $user->password = \Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password);

            // сохраняем пользователя в БД
            if($user->save())
            {
                \Yii::$app->user->login($user);
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }


        return $this->render('signup', compact('model'));
    }

    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        }

        $model->password = '';
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh();
        }
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }
}
```

User

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
        //return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Finds user by email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($email)
    {

        // echo '<pre>';
        // var_dump($email);
        // echo '</pre>';
        // exit();

        return static::findOne(['email' => $email]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        // return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        // return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        //return $this->password === $password;
        return \Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
    }
}
```

login

```
<?php

/** @var yii\web\View $this */
/** @var yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm $form */
/** @var app\models\LoginForm $model */

use yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm;
use yii\bootstrap4\Html;

$this->title = 'Вход';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-login">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'login-form',
        'layout' => 'horizontal',
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}\n{input}\n{error}",
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 col-form-label mr-lg-3'],
            'inputOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-3 form-control'],
            'errorOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-7 invalid-feedback'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox([
            'template' => "<div class=\"offset-lg-1 col-lg-3 custom-control custom-checkbox\">{input} {label}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
        ]) ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: "и ошибки нет" --- а отображение ошибок включено ли?

Comment: Включено, в других случаях всегда выдаёт ошибки
А тут он отработал и просто перекидывает на главную, так как стоит редирект, но в сессию не записал

Comment: В моделе User я на эту функцию думаю findByUsername() что с ней не так.

Толи её заменить как то надо, хотя смысл если передаётся переменная $email
Или в переменной косяк, может где не доставил

Comment: Может попробовать отладку?